# What is the quantum (e.g. Photon) phenomena that represents the EM wave impedance?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

The EM wave impedance of free space is said to be ~377 ohms and represents the ratio of Electric field strength (E) to magnetic field strength (H).  So that:
$$
\frac{E}{H} = ~377 \,\Omega
$$
When considering the photon, what aspect of the photon reflects this $E/M$ ratio or wave impedance?

Comment: Does [this website](http://redshift.vif.com/JournalFiles/V17NO3PDF/V17N3CA1.pdf) help? If so I can try to find some of the references, etc.

Comment: @heather  I will read the paper to see if it helps.  It may.

Comment: @heather       My first fast read of the paper raises more questions.  Further study would require that I investigate the basis of his arguments which seem fishy to me -- not sure I trust his paper.  However, the paper does raise some other interesting questions about physical or quantum origins of the permittivity/permeability of free-space.

Comment: okay. That was really the only thing I found. I'll look for some of the sources online so if you want you can look to where he based his arguments.

Comment: The impedance exists regardless of the attributes of a particular charged particle, so that wouldn't make a difference. Although i don't understand it enough to give any details, I believe you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity as a starting point. Specifically, consider the portion of an electric field that contributes to the relativistic magnetic fields (it has to do with the speed of the particle carrying the field).

Comment: @Digiproc      Yes,  I actually already know how free space impedance is derived and the relationship of permittivity and permeability with the speed of light.  I am beginning to think though that my question could have been asked in a more specific way as it now looks too broad to me.  A more accurate question would focus on the photon/quanta interaction with what I called "free space" where the wave impedance is the "classical" description of that interaction.  Not sure how to pose that question though.

Comment: @K7PEH, here are the first sources I've found: [9](http://www.electronspin.org/22.htm), [5](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/40/17/F03/pdf), [15](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/51/1/123/pdf), [17](http://redshift.vif.com/JournalFiles/V17NO3PDF/V17N3CA2.pdf). The numbers correspond with the citation number in the original paper. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @heather  thank you for your efforts.  Unfortunately, this morning (still morning in my location) I have run out of time for the day.  I will have to take a look at the paper references later.

Comment: @K7PEH, no problem. If I find more sources I'll post them as comments. Have a good day!

Comment: Why would photon reflect a classical wave impedance? A photon is part of the properties of a quantum field, not the entirety of its properties.

Comment: For a discussion of vacuum impedance see [Why does vaccum have a nonzero characteristic impedance towards electromagnetic radiation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79364/why-does-vaccum-have-a-nonzero-characteristic-impedance-towards-electromagnetic)

Comment: And the strength of the field in space is exactly the thing that dictates the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, but the impedance of free space is set by the choice of units. If you use natural or Planck units where $c$ and $\hbar$ and other constants are 1, the Planck impedance comes out to be about 30. More to the point, Planck units sets Coulomb's constant $\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} = 1$. This represents a choice of units.

To the point. If instead you set the permitivity $\epsilon_0 = 1$, along with $c=1$, then the permeability $\mu_0$ is also 1, and the impedance of free space is also 1.

It is simply units, there is no physics behind the 377 ohms.

See Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units

Comment: Of course that there is no physics behind the 377 ohms.  But, that is not my question -- the units themselves are of zero interest to me.  It is the interaction that my question was about but yesterday I realized that I did not ask the question specific enough.  Still processing some of the other resources and other related questions posted here.